# leaf_allocation_count in dm_db_index_operational_stats not changing on insert bulk

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2016, database-internals, bulk-insert

I was doing some index maintenance on a SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU2 and I noticed something I couldn't explain.

I've a clustered index on a table of about 66 million rows and rows are added throughout the entire day, so new pages are added. I would expect that the leaf_allocation_count of `sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats` would increase but the value is always the same, it is never higher than 1.

This is the script I used to determine leaf_allocation_count:

```
select o.name,i.name,i.type_desc,ios.leaf_insert_count,leaf_delete_count,leaf_ghost_count,leaf_update_count,leaf_allocation_count , range_scan_count,
singleton_lookup_count,forwarded_fetch_count   
from sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(my_dbid,my_objectid,null,null) ios  
inner join sys.objects o on o.object_id=ios.object_id  
inner join sys.indexes i on i.object_id=o.object_id and i.index_id=ios.index_id
```

This is the index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_clustered] ON [dbo].[Orders]
(
    [ORDERNR] ASC,
    [TRANSACT] ASC,
    [TRANSID] ASC
)
```

This is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ORDERS](
    [TRANSID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ITEM] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [ORDERNR] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [SERIALNR] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [TRANSACT] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [TIME] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [STATE] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [SUPPLIER] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [idx_TRANSID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [TRANSID] ASC
    )
)
```

The insert query that is used most of the time:

```
insert bulk [dbo].[ORDERS] 
(
    [TRANSID] nvarchar(10),
    [ITEM] nvarchar(10),
    [ORDERNR] nvarchar(10),
    [SERIALNR] nvarchar(10),
    [TRANSACT] nvarchar(10),
    [DATE] datetime,
    [TIME] nvarchar(5),
    [STATE] nvarchar(10),
    [SUPPLIER] nvarchar(10)
)
```

So I wrote a small .Net application to do a 'insert bulk'. When I checked the dmv the leaf_allocation_count did not change. When I do a regular insert then the leaf_allocation_count increases.

Next I created an Extened Event (I found on sqlskills.com) to track the page splits:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM sys.server_event_sessions 
            WHERE name = 'SQLskills_TrackPageSplits')
        DROP EVENT SESSION [SQLskills_TrackPageSplits] 
        ON SERVER

-- Create the Event Session to track LOP_DELETE_SPLIT transaction_log operations in the server
CREATE EVENT SESSION [SQLskills_TrackPageSplits]
ON    SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.transaction_log(
    WHERE operation = 11  -- LOP_DELETE_SPLIT 
      AND database_id = 6 -- CHANGE THIS BASED ON TOP SPLITTING DATABASE!
)
ADD TARGET package0.histogram(
    SET filtering_event_name = 'sqlserver.transaction_log',
        source_type = 0, -- Event Column
        source = 'alloc_unit_id');
GO

-- Start the Event Session Again
ALTER EVENT SESSION [SQLskills_TrackPageSplits]
ON SERVER
STATE=START;
GO
```

I ran my .Net application again and looked at the result of the Extended Event:

```
SELECT
    o.name AS table_name,
    i.name AS index_name,
    tab.split_count,
    i.fill_factor
FROM (    SELECT 
            n.value('(value)[1]', 'bigint') AS alloc_unit_id,
            n.value('(@count)[1]', 'bigint') AS split_count
        FROM
        (SELECT CAST(target_data as XML) target_data
         FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions AS s 
         JOIN sys.dm_xe_session_targets t
             ON s.address = t.event_session_address
         WHERE s.name = 'SQLskills_TrackPageSplits'
          AND t.target_name = 'histogram' ) as tab
        CROSS APPLY target_data.nodes('HistogramTarget/Slot') as q(n)
) AS tab
JOIN sys.allocation_units AS au
    ON tab.alloc_unit_id = au.allocation_unit_id
JOIN sys.partitions AS p
    ON au.container_id = p.partition_id
JOIN sys.indexes AS i
    ON p.object_id = i.object_id
        AND p.index_id = i.index_id
JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON p.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.is_ms_shipped = 0;
```

Above query returned one row with a split_count of 1. This corresponds with what I see in dm_db_index_operational_stats.

Can somebody explain why the leaf_allocation_count isn't increasing when executing a 'insert bulk'? Are full pages added so no splits are occurring?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug.

I have the same issue with a normal INSERT on 2016 SP2, but not on 2012. Interestingly, an index rebuild will allow `leaf_allocation_count` to be updated for a while afterwards.

Please note [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-operational-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) says `leaf_allocation_count` corresponds to a leaf-level page split, not the total number of leaf pages for the index. I built testing code that tracks page splits in addition to the operational stats dmv.

Setup:

```
USE TestDB
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS leafmealone
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.leafmealone (
ID INT,
bah UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
humbug CHAR(1000)
)
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ouch
SELECT TOP 1 cntr_value INTO #ouch
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE counter_name = 'Page Splits/sec'
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC #dothesplits AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @t bigint = (SELECT TOP 1 cntr_value FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE counter_name = 'Page Splits/sec')
    SELECT @t - cntr_value AS page_splits FROM #ouch
    UPDATE #ouch SET cntr_value = @t
END
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC #getinfo AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT o.name,i.type_desc,ios.leaf_insert_count,leaf_delete_count,leaf_ghost_count,leaf_update_count,leaf_allocation_count, ios.nonleaf_allocation_count
    from sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(DB_ID(),OBJECT_ID('dbo.leafmealone'),null,null) ios  
    inner join sys.objects o on o.object_id=ios.object_id  
    inner join sys.indexes i on i.object_id=o.object_id and i.index_id=ios.index_id
    EXEC dbo.#dothesplits
END
GO
```

These don't push `leaf_allocation_count` above 1

```
INSERT dbo.leafmealone
SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), NEWID(), 'grrrr'
FROM master..spt_values
GO

#getinfo
GO

UPDATE dbo.leafmealone
SET bah = NEWID()
WHERE ID%5 =0
GO

#getinfo
GO
```

After rebuilding, `INSERT` will show leaf allocations (splits) correctly, but `UPDATE` will not. In 2012, both will show an increasing count with each execution, corresponding to the number of page splits.

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.leafmealone REBUILD
GO

#getinfo
GO

INSERT dbo.leafmealone
SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), NEWID(), 'grrrr'
FROM master..spt_values
GO

#getinfo
GO
```

Comment: I did some testing with the update statement and in my test the leaf allocations changed correctly. Just the bulk insert behaves incorrectly.